# Serialize ternary tree in c

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, tree, ternary-tree

I am writing ternary tree for string lookup in c.

So far I am able to store strings and check whether string exists.

Example insert

```
Node *node_link(Node *this, char *line) {
 26   if(!this) {
 27     this = node_create(*line);
 28   }
 29   if(*line < this->ch) {
 30     this->left = node_link(this->left, line);
 31   } else if(*line == this->ch) {
 32     if(*(++line) == 0) {
 33       this->there = TRUE;
 34       return this;
 35     } else {
 36       this->mid = node_link(this->mid, line);
 37     }
 38   } else {
 39     this->right = node_link(this->right, line);
 40   }
 41   return this;
 42 }
```

I need to get back the strings that I inserted. For example if I inserted

```
hat
cat
catpost
tent
tents
square
squarish
```

I should be able to extract the list with same strings. I do not get it if I do tree traversal (DFS). How can I get the list of stored items?

Example traversal

```
void node_walk_link(Node *this, char *line) {
 44   if(this) {
 45     node_walk_link(this->left, line);
 46     node_walk_link(this->right, line);
 47     node_walk_link(this->mid, line_push(line, this->ch, 0));
 48   }
 49 }
```

Also how can find union of two ternary trees? That have items from both trees without duplicates.

Comment: in a first look, it seems like you just need to add this line in your node_walk_link function :
insert before line 45 : print node_walk_link

Comment: i don't need to print. i need to collect words to a list.

Comment: Word `this` is important keyword in some languages (like C++), and it is confusing if some variable is named so. I would recommend to rename `this` to something else.

Comment: Also, it seems like you have several questions. One is how to traverse a ternary tree, and another is how to find a union of two ternary trees. It is better to have only one question per page. The other question should be asked in separate post.

Comment: And now to clarify your main question. For serialization do you want the output list to be ordered exactly like the input list? If not, is ordering important at all, and what should the ordering be?

Comment: What about visiting the tree to print all words and then serialize the list, and use it again to rebuild the tree when needed? about the visit, you should visit "smaller" children first, then current element, then "bigger" children. it depend on wich order you store elements

Comment: @Dialecticus the words should be the same as entered and the order is not important

Comment: Then what is exactly the problem? You have the code that traverses the tree. When `this->mid` is null (or when `this->ch` is 0) write the `line` (or save it somewhere).

Comment: well the calls are recursive and i get `cat
catpost
catposthat
catposthatsquare
catposthatsquareish
catposthatsquareishtent
catposthatsquareishtents
catposthatsquareishtents` still need to extract words from there

Comment: @php-- ok, so instead of printing it, just add it to a list and it will work! i dont see any problem with you code! just use a vector and pass it by reference to you traverse function, and each time you see a node, add it to the vector and just pass the vector along!!!

Comment: figured something out. solution [here (second.c)](https://bitbucket.org/npavlicevic/sept_04/src/868c5e98fc51ae15f50ca9240e9e7f83017952e0?at=master)